# "Ать-два, левой!"

Tags: этимология

Вот это самое "ать" — что это? И почему не "раз-два"?

Comment: Посмотрела этимологию "ать-два"... От шведск. ett «один» — шведск. två «два».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ать — (83) част. В модальн. знач. Да, пусть (с личн. формой): Тако аже роускии гость биѥть сѩ. оу ризѣ. или на гочкомь березе. латине то не надъбѣ. ате промьжю събою оурѩдѩте сѩ. Гр 1229, сп. А (смол.); или немѣчьскыи гость иметь сѩ бити межю собою… …   **Словарь древнерусского языка (XI-XIV вв.)**

Ать -"пусть, пускай", часто в др.-русск. предложениях с оптативным значением; ср. также др.-польск. ać, др.-чеш. at'; см. Ягич, AfslPh 6, 285; Шахматов, AfslPh 7, 65. Из с. а и част. ti; первонач. dat. ethicus ti "тебе", рано сокращенный в tь. Ср. также др.-русск. тоть, др.-польск. toć. Вряд ли др.-русск. ти, ть можно связывать с лит. te- из форм желательного накл., вопреки Ягичу; см. там же.
**Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс. М. Р. Фасмер. 1964—1973.**

Comment: Не думаю, что это то же "ать", с каким мы имеем дело. Связь не просматривается. Хотя интересно, конечно само по себе.

Comment: Да, согласна))).

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКаштанова . Смотря какое тут АТЬ - армейское или "цивильное" . Есть и то и другое <<АТЬ>> . Смотрите в моём ответе ниже .

Answer (score 0):

Шведы тут ни при чём . Поддерживаю ответ **@Екатерина Каштанова** - здесь древнерусская форма со значением <<**ПУСТЬ**>> , <<**ДА**>> , <<**ЖЕ**>> , <<**ТАК**>> . Восклицание **АТЬ!** или также **АТЬ-ЯТЬ!** , - устаревшая языковая форма , -  именно этот смысл и содержит . Смотрите **"Полный церковно-славянский словарь" магистра Гр. Дьяченко** на стр .28 (интернет/ссылка - [ПЦСС стр. 28](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0028.htm)) - **Ати** , **Ато** , **Атъ** , **Ать** . Скриншот ниже .    ============================================================================= [image: Ати - Ать] ======================================================================== Однако , применительно к армейскому <<**АТЬ-ДВА**>> нам следует принять ивритную этимологию . В военной терминологии немало иврита . На иврите **אט** , по-буквенно : алеф - тет (*запись иврита справа-налево*) , в озвучке - АТ , означает <<**МЕДЛЕННО** , **ТИХО** , **ПОНЕМНОГУ**>> . **АТЬ-ДВА !** это неформальная команда , - и она подается , когда идут строем , акцентируя на чёткое уставное выполнение элементов движения ног или , как бы , печатания шага ,  а также обычно сочетается с ВЫШЕ НОГУ ! - это уже формальная команда ; или , ещё говорят , *шаг по разделению*  . А такое движение не может производиться быстро . Я это дело помню конкретно - два года срочной в Советской Армии . Смотрите по он-лайн ИРИС-словарю д-ра Баруха Подольского (интернет/ссылка [Ирис-словарь](http://www.slovar.co.il/translate.php)). Скриншот ниже . И здесь феномен , когда иврит сочетается с русским - типа , как говорится , *смесь французкого с нижегородским* . ================================================================================= [image: ИРИС-словарь]

Comment: Связывать тему армейской шагистики с МЕДЛЕННО, ТИХО, ПОНЕМНОГУ странно и смешно. Особенно, при команде «шире шаг» или переходе на бег, а бегут-то тоже в одном ритме.